# Typesetting Long URLs with ConTeXt

Tags: context

I’m trying to typeset a lengthy URL in ConTeXt MKIV. The URL appears correctly in the resulting PDF when I use `hyphenatedurl`, but the hyperlink is wrong in two ways. First, only the first line of the URL in the PDF is a hyperlink. Second, the hyperlink target is incorrectly set to be just the first line of the URL.

Here is some example code that produces this problem for me:

```
% !TEX TS-program = ConTeXt (LuaTeX)

\starttext
\hyphenatedurl{http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?Search_Arg=TX0008128881&Search_Code=REGS&PID=H2kE07My-dH7holsSiJLceSpl&SEQ=20170626171039&CNT=25&HIST=1}
\stoptext
```

On my system, this generates a PDF containing the URL printed over three lines, with line breaks as follows:

```
http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?Search_Arg=TX0008128881&Search
_Code=REGS&PID=H2kE07My-dH7holsSiJLceSpl&SEQ=20170626171039&CNT
=25&HIST=1
```

Of these three lines, only the first line is clickable/interactive, and its target is incorrectly set to `http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?Search_Arg=TX0008128881&Search`, rather than the full URL.

How can I set the hyperlink correctly? Alternatively, how can I turn off the hyperlink altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I get no hyperlink at all, which is what I expect because `\hyphenatedurl` only typesets the URL and doesn't make a link.  And even if I made a link using `\goto{<text>}[url(<link>)]` it wouldn't work because interaction is not turned on.  It seems to me that some heuristic of your PDF viewer is trying to detect the link and transform it into something clickable.  This however fails on the line break.

It is very easy though to set up a clickable link from within ConTeXt.  I also put an empty `style` because I don't like bold links.  See the [Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupinteraction) for further configuration.

```
\setupinteraction[state=start,style=]

\define[1]\hyperlink{\goto{\hyphenatedurl{#1}}[url(#1)]}

\starttext

\hyperlink{http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?Search_Arg=TX0008128881&Search_Code=REGS&PID=H2kE07My-dH7holsSiJLceSpl&SEQ=20170626171039&CNT=25&HIST=1}

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had been using `\setupinteraction` to try to turn OFF the hyperlink, but it never occurred to me that my PDF viewer may have been interpreting the text as a hyperlink on its own. Your explanation makes perfect sense.